# Proving that a function attains maximum in [0,$\infty$)

Tags: calculus, limits

$f$ is a continuous function at $x\geq0$ and $f(0)=1$. Also, for $x>0$, $f\leq\frac{\sin x + x}x$

How do we prove it attains a maximum?

I know the limit of $\frac{\sin x + x}x$ at $\infty$ is 1 and the limit at $0^+$ is 2.

Also, the limit of $f$ at $0^+$ is 1.

I get why it must attain a maximum but I can't turn it into a formal proof.

Comment: To obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M =\sup \{f(x): x \geq 0\}$. Whether this is finite or $\infty$ there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n) \to M$. If there is  subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to $\infty$ then we get $M = 1$ because $f(x_{n_k}) \to 1$. Hence the maximum is attained at $x=0$.

If there is no such subsequence then  $(x_n)$ is bounded. Hence it has  subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to some $x$. In this case $f(x) =\lim f(x_{n_k})=M$ so the maximum is attained at $x$.